# Launchd PATH issue with TeamCity

Tags: macos, environment-variables, teamcity, launchd

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249381/launchd-osx-not-running-bash-with-teamcity-agent), and got everything working appropriately. The build agent is launching, RAM disk is being created.

It seems that there is an issue with the PATH environment variable. When I run the same command from terminal, all my builds build fine. When it is launched from launchd, I get errors like "can not find mono" or "can not find nuget" both of those paths are environment variables.

How can I modify the PATH variable for a launchd file?

Here is my Launch Agent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.datafinch.teamcity</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/administrator/startup.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

And here is the script **startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

DISK=`/usr/bin/hdiutil attach -nobrowse -nomount ram://16777216`

/usr/sbin/diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "RamDiskCache" $DISK


/Users/administrator/buildAgent/bin/agent.sh start
```

When I set the PATH explicitly in my startup.sh it still doesnt work.